# How to capture groups in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm having a hard time capturing groups in htaccess with a 301 redirect.

My rule is `RedirectMatch 301 ^/viewitems/([_\-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([_\-a-zA-Z0-9]+) http://example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=$2&dir=desc&order=relevance`

but with a test url of

`http://example.com/viewitems/underground-hardwar/manhole-cable-hooks`

it builds a url that looks like this:

`http://example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=manhole-cable-hooks/viewitems/underground-hardwar/manhole-cable-hooksdir=desc/viewitems/underground-hardwar/manhole-cable-hooksorder=relevance`

Apparently, replacing every `&` with every capture group. What is going on and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you escape `&` with `\&` in the replacement does that work?

Comment: Nope, didn't affect it at all

Comment: For completeness, here is the rest of my redirects, in case of any conflict: http://pastebin.com/KNpHRe5R

Comment: So this did the trick: 

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/viewitems/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+) http://example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=$2\&dir=desc\&order=relevance`

I'll give the answer to anyone who can explain to me why that works and my original does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache uses PCRE so I believe the unescaped `&` does what the perl does with `$&` which is, it holds the string of the last pattern matched, in this case:

```
/viewitems/underground-hardwar/manhole-cable-hooks
```

So what happens is that for each `&` it replaces it with the above.

That's why the `&` needs to be escaped to give you the desired result.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/viewitems/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /catalogsearch/result/?q=$2\&dir=desc\&order=relevance
```